# Extend validity periods of customers

Tags: sql-server

I have a customer id mapping table as the one below.

```
+----+------------+------------+---------+---------+
| ID | Valid_from |  Valid_to  | Custnr1 | Custnr2 | 
+----+------------+------------+---------+---------+
|  1 | 2018-11-05 | 2019-03-04 |   50000 | XYZ     |
|  2 | 2019-03-04 | 2019-10-31 |   50000 | XYZ     |
|  3 | 2019-10-31 | 2020-03-06 |   50000 | XYZ     |
|  4 | 2020-03-06 | 9999-12-31 |   50000 | XYZ     |
|  5 | 2019-05-31 | 9999-12-31 |   70000 | ABC     |
|  6 | 2019-06-20 | 2019-07-01 |   90000 | LMN     |
+----+------------+------------+---------+---------+
```

It holds historical mappings (Custnr1, Custnr2).

The table is equipped with valid_from, valid_to columns.

The periods of the same mapping can in some cases be adjacent which makes some of the rows redundant.

I search a solution where I can obtain the following table:

```
+----+------------+------------+---------+---------+
| ID | Valid_from |  Valid_to  | Custnr1 | Custnr2 | 
+----+------------+------------+---------+---------+
|  1 | 2018-11-05 | 9999-12-31 |   50000 | XYZ     |
|  5 | 2019-05-31 | 9999-12-31 |   70000 | ABC     |
|  6 | 2019-06-20 | 2019-07-01 |   90000 | LMN     |
+----+------------+------------+---------+---------+
```

I use Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? This is a gaps and island problem, of which there are 100's of example on Stack Overflow. Why didn't those help you?

Comment: I could not find any related problems. But I see that gaps and island solutions is what i'm looking for. I'll dive into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Larnu stated the problem is a common problem called gaps and island problem.
It was pretty straight forward to follow this guide: https://bertwagner.com/2019/03/12/gaps-and-islands/ to obtain the answer.

```
SELECT 
Custnr1, 
Custnr2, 
min(Valid_from) AS Valid_from, 
Max(Valid_to) AS Valid_to
FROM (
SELECT 
*, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Groups.PreviousEndDate = Valid_from THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Custnr1, Custnr2 ORDER BY Groups.RN) AS IslandId
FROM (
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Custnr1, Custnr2 ORDER BY Valid_from) AS RN,
Custnr1, 
Custnr2,
Valid_from,
Valid_to,
LAG(Valid_to,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Custnr1, Custnr2 ORDER BY Valid_from) AS PreviousEndDate
FROM table) GROUPS
) Islands
GROUP BY Custnr1, Custnr2, IslandId
ORDER BY Valid_from
```

Comment: In that case actually add your answer... otherwise this is just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use From `Window Function`: `RANK()`, `Dens_Rank()` OR `Row_Number`

```
select 
MT1.ID ,
MT1.Valid_from ,
MT2.Valid_to ,
MT2.Custnr1 ,
MT2.Custnr2
from(
select 
*,
Row_Number()over (partition by Custnr2 order by Valid_from asc) [Row_rank]
from @MyTable 
) MT1
inner join (
            select * from(
            select 
            *,              
            Row_Number()over (partition by Custnr2 order by Valid_to asc) [Row_rank]
            from @MyTable 
            )temp 
)MT2 on MT2.Custnr2=MT1.Custnr2

where MT1.Row_rank=1 and MT2.Row_rank=1
```

The only difference between RANK, DENSE_RANK and ROW_NUMBER function is when there are duplicate values in the column being used in ORDER BY Clause

in this solution, it's better to use `Row_Number()`